# And operator in a Django filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a Django Rest Framework API endpoint. I would like this endpoint to retrieve all the records with the `Status` field set to `Free`, so i did this:

```
queryset = tst.objects.using('screener').filter(Status=Free)
```

Now, i want to retrieve not only the fields with the field set to `Free`, but also those with the status set to `Pending`.

I tried this:

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    criterion1 = Q(Status="Free")
    criterion2 = Q(Status="Pending")
    queryset = tst.objects.using('screener').filter(criterion1&criterion2)
```

For some reason, this view will retrieve nothing. If i try the queries individually, though, they will work:

```
queryset = tst.objects.using('screener').filter(criterion1) #works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
queryset = tst.objects.using('screener').filter(criterion1|criterion2)
```

right now in filter you are using and condition but you need a or condition

for more information you can read this [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want the & operator but the or (|)
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not